# Bivariate polynomials over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $f$ is a bivariate polynomial of degree $r$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then the
number of solutions to $f(x,y)=0$ should be less than $rp$. This can be seen
by writing $f(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^r a_i(x) y^{r-i}$ where $a_i(x)$ are univariate
polynomials of degree utmost $i$. For each fixed $x$ the $f(x,y)$ is a univariate
polynomial in $y$ of degree $r$ and only $r$ roots are possible. There are $p$
$x$'s so the total is $rp$.

I wanted to know if this is this the best bound possible. While the univariate 
case seems to be much studied, I could not find many references for this question
on multivariate polynomials.

Thanks,
Phanindra

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Versions of this question have been much studied, but it's not obvious what the correct keywords are. In this case you want to look at [algebraic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry), particularly the study of [algebraic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve), over finite fields. The relevant theorem in this subject is the [Hasse-Weil bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves#Hasse-Weil_Bound), which in turn massively generalizes to the [Weil conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures).

The Hasse-Weil bound implies that if $f$ is irreducible and a certain nonsingularity condition is met (actually I am not sure if this is necessary), the number of solutions is something like (but not quite)

$$p \pm 2g \sqrt{p}$$

where $g = \frac{(r-1)(r-2)}{2}$ by the [genus-degree formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula).  This gives a bound which is worse than your bound if $r$ is large compared to $p$ but which is substantially better if $p$ is large compared to $r$, so which bound is better depends on which regime you care about.

Of course, if $r > p$ then an even better bound than $rp$ is $p^2$...

The Hasse-Weil bound should conjecturally be tight in a suitable sense (in particular, asymptotically in $p$) by a suitable generalization of the [Sato-Tate conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sato%E2%80%93Tate_conjecture).  On the other hand, in general your bound can be tight, since $f$ may be a product of distinct linear factors. If $f$ is reducible then you should factor $f$ and apply the Hasse-Weil bound separately to each of its factors.

Comment: Qiaochu: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have no idea of algebraic geometry but I think it will be very interesting.