# Prove that homogeneous multivariate polynomial reduces to the zero polynomial given conditions on zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_r)$ be a homogeneous polynomial. Then
>   $P(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r) = 0$ for all $(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r)
>  \in \mathbb{R}^r_{+}$ such that $\sum\limits^r_{j=1} \alpha_j = 1$ if
>   and only if $P(.)$ is the zero polynomial.

I had posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807195/multivariate-polynomials-with-infinite-number-of-zeros/2807213?noredirect=1#comment5788585_2807213) also, but the wording was incorrect hence posting it as a new question again.

I think I have proven it also, using induction, with $A.\Gamma$'s help on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805121/how-to-know-if-a-given-infinite-set-of-vectors-lie-in-the-same-hyperplane/2805152?noredirect=1#comment5786019_2805152) question. I have used induction on $r$ (trivially true for $r=1$). Then for a fixed $r$ I fixed any $m \in [r]$ and used induction on the exponent of $x_m$, showing coefficients of any term with $x^0_m$ is $0$, then after removing those, coefficients of any term with $x^1_m$ is $0$ and so on, as outlined for the case $r=2$ by $A.\Gamma.$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805121/how-to-know-if-a-given-infinite-set-of-vectors-lie-in-the-same-hyperplane/2805152?noredirect=1#comment5784202_2805152).

My first question is - is the above statement correct? If not, kindly suggest suitable modifications to a correct version. Maybe I have made mistakes in the proof and hence not realizing that this is not correct.

Secondly, is there any existing result (perhaps involving fundamental theorem for multivariate polynomials, e.g.) from which this follows? I tried looking for it, found [Bezout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), but not sure if and how this can be derived using it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P$ is a homogeneous polynomial (0f degree $k$ say) $P(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n)=a^{k}P(\beta_1,..,\beta_n)=0$ for any $\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n$, where $\beta_i = \alpha_i /a$ and $a=\sum \alpha_i$ (assuming that $a \neq 0$). This proves that  $P(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n)=0$ whenever $\sum \alpha_i \neq 0$ . By continuity we get $P \equiv 0$. I an unable to suggest how the question should be modified, but, as stated, it seems quite trivial.

Comment: I didn't understand how we get $P \equiv 0$ by continuity. So are you saying we're showing that it is zero for any vector the sum of whose components is not zero, and then by continuity it is zero for any vector, and hence it is the zero polynomial?

Comment: So the induction argument suggested by A.$\Gamma$. here is not necessary? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805121/how-to-know-if-a-given-infinite-set-of-vectors-lie-in-the-same-hyperplane/2805152?noredirect=1#comment5784202_2805152

Comment: @Canine360 If $a_1+a_2+..+a_n=0$ then $(a_1+\frac 1 n)+a_2+..+a_n\neq 0$ and $(a_1+\frac 1 n,a_2,...,a_n) \to (a_1+\frac 1 n,a_2,...,a_n)$

Comment: But what if some of the $\beta_i$'s are negative and some are positive? The condition only holds for non-negative $\alpha_i$'s as mentioned.

Comment: If a polynomial is zero on $\mathbb R_{+}^{r}$ the it is zero eveywhere.

Comment: On second thoughts, doesn't having infinite number of zeros itself imply it's the zero polynomial? e.g. as discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245503/bivariate-polynomials-over-finite-fields

Comment: In the reference the polynomials are over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yeah that question was meant as an example. But wouldn't a non-zero multivariate polynomial over the reals also have finite no. of zeros? And hence if it has infinite no. of zeros wouldn't that mean it is the zero polynomial?

Comment: $f(x,y)=xy$ has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: OK I think my understanding was not clear. If there exists an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P(.)$ is zero everywhere on the ball, then we can say it is the zero polynomial right?

Comment: You are right. If $P$ is zero on an open ball the it is zero everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$x+y=0$$ which has infinitely many solutions, $y=-x, x\in R$.